# SSRS Report, Changed Parameter value can not be passed to drill through report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, drillthrough

I have been requested to create a SSRS report.

Report have one parameter X with value X1(default value) and X2.

Add a textbox display @X and set Action on that textbox go to report to itself.

Pass @X as parameter.

Run report X1 displayed in textbox. Change @X from X1 to X2 -> Click on the textbox.

X1 is passed instead of X2.

Is there a way to pass the changed parameter value without click ViewReport button.

Comment: Unfortunately for you there is not. The report created has the x1 value embedded. You need to rerun the report to re-embed the x2 value.